# Get Date List from weeknumber c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

I have a function that get the current weeknumber from the given date

e.g.

```
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(GregorianCalendarTypes.Localized);
return cal.GetWeekOfYear(date, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
```

gives back weeknumber 40 for DateTime.Now.

So my question is , also my problem, i need to get the dates in the returned week. I've tried several thing and none so for worked.

Comment: You mean, you want the dates to be produced from week number?

Comment: Can you post one of things you have tried?

Comment: Do you need this for a query? If so, SQL has it's own functions for that. Might be worth taking a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this function to get the first date of a week:

```
public static DateTime FirstDateOfWeek(int year, int weekOfYear)
{
    DateTime jan1 = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
    int daysOffset = Convert.ToInt32(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek) - Convert.ToInt32(jan1.DayOfWeek);
    DateTime firstWeekDay = jan1.AddDays(daysOffset);
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo curCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    int firstWeek = curCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(jan1, curCulture.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule, curCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek);
    if (firstWeek <= 1) {
        weekOfYear -= 1;
    }
    return firstWeekDay.AddDays(weekOfYear * 7);
}
```

Then you can get all dates in this week in the following way:

```
var firstDate = FirstDateOfWeek(2012, 40);
var allWeekDays = new List<DateTime>();
allWeekDays.Add(firstDate);
var currentDate = firstDate;
for(int d = 1; d < 7; d++)
{
    currentDate=currentDate.AddDays(1);
    allWeekDays.Add(currentDate);
}
```

or in one line:

```
var week = Enumerable.Range(0,7).Select(d => firstDate.AddDays(d)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the class **Week** of the [Time Period Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET):

```
Week week = new Week( new DateTime( 2012, 03, 21 ) );
Console.WriteLine( "week #: ", week.WeekOfYear );
Console.WriteLine( "week first day: ", week.FirstDayOfWeek );
Console.WriteLine( "week last day: ", week.LastDayOfWeek );
```

Additional, the class Week supports ISO 8601 week numbering and custom cultures.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the first and last day in the week simply by looking at the weekday of the given date, and look for the monday:

```
DateTime firstDay = date.Date;
while (firstDay.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday) {
  firstDay = date.AddDays(-1);
}
DateTime lastDay = firstDay.AddDays(6);
```